# Check if node is an articulate node and if yes, output the subgraphs

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, graph

Consider a graph:

```
  5   3 
 /|\ /|\
6-7- 1 2-4
```

To simplify, the adjacency list of the graph is:

```
1: 2, 5, 7
2: 1, 3, 4
3: 2, 4
4: 2, 3
5: 1, 6, 7
6: 5, 7
7: 5, 6, 1
```

So, 1 here is an articulate node which means that removing 1 causes the graph to divide into 2 sub-graphs. What I am trying to do is make a function, say func(input_node, graph) where the input node in the example is 1.

So, this should return the nodes of the 2 sub-graphs produced:

```
2 // number of sub-graphs
[5, 6, 7] // sub-graph 1
[2, 3, 4] // sub-graph 2
```

My approach to the problem. I generated all the possible articulate points for a graph in O(V+E) and then checked if the node is present in that list. If yes, I get the connected nodes for the input node (here, 1), and perform an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation to get the set of nodes which are not connected. The algorithm is expensive. Can anyone suggest me an optimal solution for the problem?

Comment: You should provide your code. Also: if you are looking for the algorithm, and not the code, then remove the python tag. Otherwise, your question should have some python code, including the code that defines the graph data structure.

Comment: The "drawing" of the graph does not correspond with the adjacency list that you have given.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the node to be deleted *x*. An algorithm for this would look like this:

1. For each unvisited neighbor of the node *x* perform step 2:
2. Collect all nodes that can be reached starting from that neighbor, without ever visiting node *x*. This can for instance be done with a depth-first search.

   - If the resulting set of nodes contains some other neighbors of *x*, then don't perform step 2 for it (they are marked as visited).
3. Return the sets found in step 2.

This process will traverse each edge at most once, so it has *O(E)* time complexity.

Here is how that could be done in Python:

```
def remove(node, graph):
    # mark the node as visited so it cannot be crossed in any of the searches
    visited = set([node])

    def dfs(parent):
        nodes = []
        if parent not in visited:
            visited.add(parent)
            nodes.append(parent)
            for child in graph[parent]:
                nodes.extend(dfs(child))
        return nodes

    subgraphs = []
    for neighbor in graph[node]:
        if neighbor not in visited:
            subgraphs.append(dfs(neighbor))

    return subgraphs
```

You can call the above function with your sample data like this:

```
graph = {
    "1": ["2", "5", "7"],
    "2": ["1", "3", "4"],
    "3": ["2", "4"],
    "4": ["2", "3"],
    "5": ["1", "6", "7"],
    "6": ["5", "7"],
    "7": ["5", "6", "1"]
}

print(remove("1", graph)) # [['2', '3', '4'], ['5', '6', '7']]
```